# Can someone provide a scenario where a prepared statement is beneficial for efficiency?

Tags: performance, prepared-statement

Not for sql injection protection.  I am aware of that benefit, but as far as the compiled part and it being more efficient, I cannot find a scenario where it would benefit *for efficiency*.  I was hoping for that here.  Vague I know, but I don't know where to ask other than here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One can easily list that benefits of prepared statements

1. You get rid of compilation overhead
2. You get rid of the need to prepare an execution plan
3. Since not statement, but only parameters need to travel through wire, you gain bandwidth.

If you have one statement to work millions of times during a long time-span, all that items are important for efficiency. If it is easy to develop (like stored procedures), it is a win win situation, but...

I have once had to develop a code that directly connects to AS/400 system using "C with Embedded SQL" which you write sql in your C code, give it to the preprocessor to output compilable code and a binder file, then give binder file to the as/400 system to prepare statement. All because they refused to install ODBC support their to server.

It was a pain to write and test that code. It was working *very* slow, and changing anything would definitely break the system for sure. It was not **efficient** to write a code like this.

Efficiency depends on variables which varies depending on your point of view.

In my sample, AS/400 guys were happy since they kept they system **efficient** by not installing some *cr.p* software on it. Customer was happy, since their method of forcing developers to use **inefficient** methods to write code was **efficient** enough to keep it in timeline. It was **efficient** for network admin since only minimal data is transmitted over network (even no metadata). It was very **inefficient** for developer since it was time consuming and error-prone. But it was also **efficient** for same developer to get something that will "look good" on a resume.

You see now?

Answer (score 0):

The scenario is simple:  transaction processing.

As Edokan says, preparing a statement eliminates the overhead of compiling the SQL and creating the execution plan.  In a more complex query, this overhead is minimal.  However, if you are running 100 or 1000 transactions per second, then this overhead can interfere with efficiently using the database.

Of course, the query plan may not be the best, especially when the statistics on the underlying tables change.  The characteristics at prepare-time are used to determine the best query plan.  These may change over time, and a different query plan might become better.  This is more of an issue for more complex queries.  Since these typically take longer to run, so the compile overhead is less of an issue.